# How can I tell Timeshift how many backups to keep using CLI?

Tags: timeshift

The GUI version of Timeshift offers the ability to automatically keep the last X backups:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teejee2008/timeshift/master/images/settings_schedule.png

As far as I can see, there is no such option using CLI:
https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift#readme
https://manpages.debian.org/testing/timeshift/timeshift.1.en.html

Is there such an option using CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `/etc/timeshift.json` file to set these values. The [timeshift.json file in the repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teejee2008/timeshift/master/files/timeshift.json) shows these values to be the defaults:

```
  "count_monthly" : "2",
  "count_weekly" : "3",
  "count_daily" : "5",
  "count_hourly" : "6",
  "count_boot" : "5"
```

P.S.: I found this approach from [Issue #288](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/288) on the same Github repo.

Comment: Thank you. Should be better documented.

Comment: @NoExpert That's a fair point. There is [another issue discussion](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/300) which states that Timeshift has dependencies on GTK3, which is a GUI system. The program must have been conceived and built as a GUI application. That is probably is why the CLI documentation is lacking.

Comment: I believe `/etc/timeshift/timeshift.json` is the file to edit.   
`/etc/timeshift.json` shows the default valuees